# VBA - Change GetUniques to allowing duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through a folder which opens many files and inputs data into a mastersheet.

It currently works well except now I need the code to allow for duplicates and I have been using a GetUniques function. How would I go about fixing that?

**GetUnique is in sections 3, 4, and function in 8.**

Here is my code if that helps you at all. Thank you for any guidance you can give!

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, d As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.UpdateLinks = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2




    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'print file name to Column 1

            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet


'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetUniques(hc.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the masterfile, column 3
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If

'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetUniques(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
                    End If
                Else
                    'header not found on source worksheet
                End If

'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                        'print the file name to Column 1
                        StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = objFile.Name
                        'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                        With ws
                            .Range("J1").Copy StartSht.Cells(i, 4)
                        End With
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                'move to next file
                Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
'(7)
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetUniques(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then
            dict.Add v, ""
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetUniques = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        If Trim(c.Value) = sHeader Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is `GetUnique` (or `GetUniques`) and where can we find it?

Comment: @user3964075 Yes! GetUnique function is used to get multiple values but eliminate any duplicates. I didn't know if there was a short way to fix it or if I would need to reconfigure my entire code for those sections. Any ideas are helpful!

Comment: This explains it a little bit with an example if that helps at all http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/649576-extract-unique-values-one-column-using-visual-basic-applications.html

Comment: There is no reference in your code to this function, and it would be nice to include the code the function itself in your question.

Comment: I recognize the "CuttingTool" reference in here from a previous question, and I must say, your code looks to have made tremendous strides from that previous question. Well done! That said, I agree with the others, I don't see any reference to the `GetUnique` that you're questioning.

Comment: So sorry, updated the code (_accidentally put in old code format_)

Comment: Wow thank you @FreeMan , that is very nice of you to say. Yes, that was an error on my part not putting in the most updated code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the *simplest* fix would be to change your `GetUniques()` function from its current to this:

```
Function GetUniques(ch As Range) As Object
    Dim dict As Object, rng As Range, c As Range, v
    Set dict = New Collection
    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            dict.Add v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetUniques = dict
End Function
```

That said, your `GetUniques()` function no longer gets unique values, so it should really be renamed, and all your calls to is should be adjusted to call the new function name.

This is also not the most elegant solution, as I believe that you should be able to simply add the range passed into `GetUniques` to your destination, but I'm not parsing your code well enough this morning to identify the full set of changes necessary. I'd suggest getting the code working with a function call, then you could post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for tips on improving your *functioning* code.

Comment: Ah, yes wonderful idea @FreeMan . The only problem is I come up with an error message at the line `dict.Add v, ""` saying _error: this key is already associated with an element of this collection_. I'm not sure how to fix that...
Wow I didn't know about Code Review that's fantastic. Thank you for that tip

Comment: Ah yes, a `Dictionary`, by default, only allows unique values - one of its great strengths. I've updated the code to change `dict` to be a `Collection` instead. `Collections` will allow duplicate values, which is exactly what you're after. Of course, that means your variable name `dict` is now misleading, so you should really change it, but that's a CR issue... :)

Comment: Hm.. unfortuantely I get back the same error.  Your explanation made complete sense so I'm not sure why that wouldn't fix the issue.. @FreeMan

Comment: Change `dict.add v, ""` to dict.add v`. The `""` is providing the optional key (which must be unique, even in a `collection`). Without it you can just add as much data as you want without any unique constraints.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you for your explanations, they help a lot.
Now I get an error in section (3) line `d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)` saying _Object doesn't support this property or method_. Would that be because I now have multiple values?

Comment: `Dict` is no longer a dictionary, so it doesn't have a `.keys` property/method. Not sure exactly what you're doing with the `Application.Transpose()` there, so you'll have to work through that. Looks like you just need a count of the number of items you're adding? If so, `dict.count` should work.

Comment: The `Application.Transpose()` was meant to print the selected items into a maseterfile

Comment: Is there something I can put in the parentheses that would print out the selected items?